# Booting problem with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I have 12.04 Ubuntu on my notebook; but, I do have a problem with it.
I cannot boot, if I don't press anything then there is a black screen, and it does not boot.

If I press the <kbd>space</kbd> button,or any other key,for multiple times, like 20 or 25 times, for example, then it's boot in seconds normally.

How can i resolve this?

Ps:I do not have a problem with BIOS as it's already booting on first for the hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check your bios settings if the boot device priority is correctly set. Just try to check if the network is not the primary boot device or the CD-ROM device. Make the hard disk your first boot device and then check if that resolve your problem.

Comment: It's not this .... I do not have a problem with bios as it's already booting on first for the hard drive

Comment: can you provide your pc configurations?

Comment: toshiba nb200 ,  ( not dual boot with windows ) only ubuntu , hard drive 250gb ( good status  with no error ),2GB ram and core 2 duo 1.6ghz with No cd driver and 4 usb. thanks for you help

Comment: why not just then re-install and update grub.maybe that can help

Comment: I did an update on the grub but i am still having the same problems , 2 days ago i was on 11.10 and i had the same problem , i have to press the keyboard few times , to make it work.! :

Comment: what does pressing f4 key does to you?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `pci=nomsi` to the kernel parameters when it boots.  This will be in the grub menu, or extlinux.

You can test it at the same time you choose between your kernels by manuall appending it to the start line.